# Heating up a nichrome wire, MOSFET got too hot

Tags: mosfet, temperature

I'm trying to get a 37 AWG, 0.6mm diameter nichrome wire to reach 300*C so it can heat up inside of an enclosure and according to its [datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/4f54/0900766b815fcf14.pdf) that requires 5A, I cut out enough nichrome wire to offer 2.4ohm. The source provides 12V and 5A max, the MOSFET used is STFH18N60M2([datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stfh18n60m2.pdf)) and it acts as a switch and I'm sending a PWM signal(%100 duty cycle at the moment) to its gate from Arduino.

Now the nichrome wire does heat up, I don't know if it reaches 300*C but what went wrong is that the MOSFET apparently got too hot and melted the plastic of the breadboard where it was connected, I didn't think I would need a heatsink and I'm wondering if something is wrong with my circuit:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what voltage your Arduino outputs, but that MOSFET has and RdsON of 0.25 ohms even with 10V to the gate.  If you're actually running 5A through it, P=I^2R=25*0.25=6.25W, so even with 10V to the gate you'd expect it to get hot.  More likely you're putting 3.3 or 5V to the gate and your ON resistance is substantially higher.  You might want to use a MOSFET with better RdsON and add a MOSFET driver if required.

Comment: Often, when your MOSFET gets too hot it means your MOSFET wasn't fully turned on because the gate voltage was too low.

Comment: Is the NMOS really turning on and off? Or just constantly conducting via the body diode?

Comment: On your schematic transistor is updown. Internal diode conducts, the load can not be controlled. And choose MOSFET with lower voltage, it is usually smaller resistance.

Comment: Why do you need a 600 V mosfet to switch 12 V ? A 30 V mosfet will provide significantly lower RdsON, and will be much cheaper.

Comment: 5A in a breadboard? Are you sure it wasn't the overheating breadboard that heated the MOSFET? This needs to be soldered (and with adequate heatsinking on the MOSFET).

Comment: @Brian Drummond That's actually very true, though the MOSFET I'm using is still not suitable, it's the only one I already had but will keep that in mind for the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your heater at 2.4 ohms with 12 V will draw a current of I = V/R = 12/2.4 = 5 A.

While that is within the capability of the MOSFET's 13 A rating, you are failing to account for the power dissipated in the MOSFET itself.

At 5 A and 0.280 ohms RdsON you will get P = I^2*R = 5^2 * 0.280 = 25 * 0.280 = 7 watts.  The datasheet shows a Rthj-amb of 62.5 C/W.

So 7 watts will give you 7 * 62.5 = 437 C! That's WAY too hot. The max operating temperature is 150 C.

You need a heatsink capable of keeping the device below 150 C or you need a different MOSFET that will not dissipate so much heat.

Comment: Right, thanks... I didn't know anything about the Rthj-amb, guess I had to learn that the hard way. I think I will be better off with a different MOSFET with better suited parameters, I've seen most MOSFETs used in this application are connected to the Arduino(5V) through a BJT circuit, would that be something you'd advise I add to my circuit as well ?

Comment: As noted in one of the comments, to minimize power dissipation in a MOSFET you need to ensure that it's 100% on.  The Arduino output may not be able to do that.  Using a BJT allows  you to buffer the output and make sure it fully switches on the MOSFET.  But with a 5A load you will likely find that you always need a heatsink of some sort.  BTW - this is "engineering".  You don't just hook a bunch of parts together and hope for the best.  You read specs, you design,  you calculate, you test, then you have a working system.

Comment: I would definitely advise just getting a better mosfet. There are many options that have far better characteristics than this one, for example, (https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irl2505pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153565b6c032500) will be like >20x better than what you have now

Comment: If you spend a little bit more, you can get something like this (https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/alq61corkr/FAIRS44829-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) which should allow you to squeak by without a heatsink, at <100mW power dissipation

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the correct comments regarding a better MOSFET model, here is a circuit which takes a [0 to 5V] input (low is on, high is off) with 12V load. It also correctly polarizes a NMOS (the 'source' pin is connected to 0V and not inverted like in your schematics), guaranteeing a higher Vgs (you should also check this when you choose another MOSFET):

[image]

[image]